# How do you make the header row unselectable in a table that was imported into a dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

When the data loads into the dataGridView, if you click on the header column name of a particular column, it will re sort all the data in that column alphabetically.  How do I make it so you can't do that?
This is the code which builds the individual dataGrids, each on its own tab.

```
var tabPage = new TabPage(name1);
                DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();  //{ //Dock = DockStyle.Fill  // };
                grid.Location = new Point(10, 50);
                grid.Size = new Size(950, 450);
                grid.Name = "dg_" + name;


                tabPage.Controls.Add(grid);
                grid.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;
                grid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader;

                comboBox1.Items.Add(name1);
                tabControl2.TabPages.Add(tabPage);
                loadData(name, grid);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, run this loop apter you populate your grid with data. THis will set the columns not sortable

```
 foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

for datagridview there is a enumerator called DataGridViewColumnSortMode.by this you can sort out your problem

```
for (int m = 0; m <= dataGridView1.ColumnCount-1; m++)
            dataGridView1.Columns[m].SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable;
```

[Refer this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumnsortmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)